# HTTP post with ajax returning 404

Tags: javascript, ajax, http-post

I want to send a JSON object to the server and save it as a text file:

`$.post("/", { foo: bar });`

However, it does not work when I was trying to post to a certain directory:

`$.post("/SomeFolder", { foo: bar });`

It will always return 404.

---

Backend is based on flask.

Structure of the directory is like:

```
- SomeFolder
- static
- templates
- ... (other miscellaneous files...)
```

---

`Script.js`

```
function save(){
    var firstname = document.getElementById("fname").value;
    var lastname = document.getElementById("lname").value;
    var scenario = document.getElementById("scenario").value;

    document.getElementById("fname").value = "";
    document.getElementById("lname").value = "";
    document.getElementById("scenario").value = "";
    //var data = JSON.stringify(canvas_data);
    var data = []; // leave blank for compatability purpose
    var image = canvas.toDataURL();
    
    $.post("/", { fname: firstname, lname: lastname, scenario: scenario, save_cdata: data, save_image: image });
    alert(firstname + " saved!");
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    //canvas_data = { "pencil": [], "line": [], "rectangle": [], "circle": [], "eraser": [] }
}
```

---

`run.py`

```
def paintapp(template_str):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template_string(template_str)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        firstname = request.form['fname']
        lastname = request.form['lname']
        scenario = request.form['scenario']
        # data = request.form['save_cdata']
        canvas_image = request.form['save_image']
        f = open("{0}_{1}_{2}.txt".format(firstname, lastname, scenario), "w+")
        f.write(canvas_image)
        return render_template_string(template_str)
     
if __name__ == '__main__':
    port = int(os.environ.get('PORT', 65520))
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=port, debug=True)
```

Comment: This question needs more context. Are you able to include a link to your repo?

Comment: @PCDSandwichMan I am sorry that this repo is kinda hard to share, but I have updated some info in the question.